# Add a create new order button in Admin in a Varien_Data_Form

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, adminform

I've to customise a `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form` class that uses a `Varien_Data_Form`.
I've to add a insert a 'create new order button'. At the moment, I'm using this code:

```
$adminorder->addField('some_field', 'submit', array(
    'after_element_html' => '<button type="button" onclick="alert(\'Create order\')">Create new order</button>'
));
```

But of course it shows a blank submit button too. Is there a better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your save button in Adminhtml is located in your form container.  Extend a class off of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container`.  Override the method `_prepareLayout()` and from within, call `$this->_updateButton()`.

It should look something like this:

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {

    //snip ...
    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        $this->_updateButton( 'save', 'label', $this->__( 'Save My Form' ) );
        $this->_updateButton( 'delete', 'label', $this->__( 'Delete My Form' ) );

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```